# Excel Web Powerquery: Excel merges data strings in cells --> How do I delimit the data?

Tags: html, excel, powerquery, vba

I am using Excel 2016 and would like to download Odds from Oddschecker.com via the Web Powerquery function into an Excel Spreadsheet.

More specifically, I am trying to download the data from this Website:

https://www.oddschecker.com/politics/european-politics/french-election/next-president/bet-history/marine-le-pen/today#all-history

The problem I have is that some odds on this Website are being merged without space between them into single cells:

[image: Screenshot of Excel Web Powerquery]

Is there any way in Powerquery to delimit the data strings/odds so that they are not being merged?

Thank you very much in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach in the code below using recursive function fnSearchTR (embedded in the query) to drill down the HTML document until the name "TR" is found *(or after 100 iterations just to prevent endless iterating)*. I noticed that this is the place where the required data is located, at least today.
Remark: I also adjusted the second step in the code to select the "Document".

This is a more dynamic solution as it doesn't matter where in the document structure the "TR" is located; otherwise if the document structure is adjusted, then it is still possible that other "TR"'s are found first, but so far it works.
Otherwise also "TR"'s are found with other content, but these will be filtered out as errors or null values after the data type of the first column is adjusted to date.

This query also uses the function "ExpandTables" from my previous answer (I corrected the typo and added a "x", otherwise no changes in the function).

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.oddschecker.com/politics/european-politics/french-election/next-president/bet-history/marine-le-pen/today#all-history")),
    Data0 = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Caption] = "Document"){0}[Data],
    ChildrenWithTable = Table.SelectRows(Data0, each [Children] is table),

    fnSearchTR = (newChildren as table, counter as number) as table =>
    let
        Combined = Table.Buffer(Table.Combine(newChildren[Children])),
        ChildrensChildrenWithTable = Table.AddColumn(newChildren, "ChildrensChildren", each Table.SelectRows([Children], each [Children] is table)),
        ChildrensChildrenCombined = Table.Combine(ChildrensChildrenWithTable[ChildrensChildren]),
        CombinedAll = if ChildrensChildrenCombined[Name]{0} = "TR" 
                        then ChildrensChildrenCombined 
                        else if Table.RowCount(ChildrensChildrenCombined) = 0 or counter = 100
                            then Combined 
                            else @fnSearchTR(ChildrensChildrenCombined, counter + 1) 
    in
        CombinedAll,

    CombinedAll = if Table.RowCount(ChildrenWithTable) = 0 then Data0 else fnSearchTR(ChildrenWithTable, 0),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(CombinedAll, each ([Name] = "TR")),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Children"}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "ExpandTables", each ExpandTables([Children])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function",{"Children"}),
    #"Expanded ExpandTables" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "ExpandTables", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27", "Column28", "Column29"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27", "Column28", "Column29"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded ExpandTables",{{"Column1", type date}}),
    #"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Errors", each ([Column1] <> null))
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

Comment: Thanks again @MarcelBeug. However, if I copy & paste your new code, it still shows an Expression.Error: _"The Import ExpandTables matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?"_ The error happens @ `"Invoked Custom Function"` where it says further: _"The Name 'ExpandTables' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly."_ Something still seems to be wrong with the "ExpandTables" expression I think. Any idea why this is not working at my PC?

Comment: You must also copy & paste import the function from my previous post and call it ExpandTables.

Comment: AnDr: Is this solution (or the solution from @Carl Walsh) now working for you? It has been working for me for a couple of days and also today it's working fine.

Comment: Thank you so much für your help. This is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't test it, since this site is blacklisted in Russian Internet segment, I suppose there are `<cr>`s or `<lf>`s there, and they aren't transformed to new lines.
What you need is to run `Text.Replace` against all cells with data to replace these characters.
But then you'll probably need these values as separate rows, and this is far more complex task. :)

Comment: I was able to test it: strange enough there are no line breaks whatsoever in the imported table (although there must be something in the original web page). The only thing left is split by positions, but then again it will be very difficult or impossible to determine the pattern where the strings must be split.
@Eugene with the April 2017 update of Power BI Desktop, a feature was added to choose if columns must be split into new rows or in new columns.

Comment: I am actually not so familiar with 'html' but I think the reason why Powerquery does merge some Odds to one single string is that in the html source code, some odds are enclosed in one <td> tag, e.g. <td> <div class="oo"> 13/4 </div> <div class="oi"> 3 </div> <div class="oo"> 13/4 </div> </td>. Is there a way to tell Powerquery to seperate these tags?

Comment: I found another possible way to Isolate the problem: It is possible to follow the different paths until the last child <td> element in the query Editor. For instance, in childnode 23 of the HTML document, I can see two entries for 2 seperate Odds having the same date stamp so that Powerquery combines them into one single string: Formula should be `= Children23{}[Children]` Do you have any idea to implement this code into the Powerquery? @MarcelBeug, @Eugene

Comment: @AnDr Unfortunately I can't help you with exact code, since I can access this website only in browser. Can you possibly export the data from this page and add to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Gil Raviv's http://datachant.com/2017/03/30/web-scraping-power-bi-excel-power-query/

*Edit April 11, 2017: this solution is highly dependent on the structure of the website, or in other words: yesterday it worked fine, but today it doesn't, unfortunately.*

The following query with associated function works with me:

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.oddschecker.com/politics/european-politics/french-election/next-president/bet-history/marine-le-pen/today#all-history")),
    Data0 = Source{1}[Data],
    Children = Data0{0}[Children],
    Children1 = Children{1}[Children],
    Children2 = Children1{4}[Children],
    Children3 = Children2{0}[Children],
    Children4 = Children3{0}[Children],
    Children5 = Children4{0}[Children],
    Children6 = Children5{3}[Children],
    Children7 = Children6{0}[Children],
    Children8 = Children7{1}[Children],
    Children9 = Children8{3}[Children],
    Children10 = Children9{0}[Children],
    Children11 = Children10{2}[Children],
    Children12 = Children11{2}[Children],
    Children13 = Children12{0}[Children],
    Children14 = Children13{1}[Children],
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Children14,{"Children"}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "EpandTables", each EpandTables([Children])),
    #"Expanded EpandTables" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "EpandTables", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27", "Column28", "Column29"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27", "Column28", "Column29"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded EpandTables",{"Children"}),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Parsed Date" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Blank Rows",{{"Column1", each Date.From(DateTimeZone.From(_)), type date}})
in
    #"Parsed Date"
```

Function ExpandTables *(edit: #"Added Custom" line adjusted by adding Table.SelectRows)*

```
(ChildTable as table) =>
let
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(ChildTable,{"Children"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Custom", each try if [Children] is null then null else if [Children][Text]{0} <> null then [Children][Text]{0} else Lines.ToText(List.Transform(Table.SelectRows([Children], each [Children] <> null)[Children], each _[Text]{0})) otherwise null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Children"}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns")
in
    #"Transposed Table"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MarcelBeug. But I am getting an error message ("Expression.Error") with reference to "EpandTables" if I copy & paste your code from above into the advanced editor. Does not fix even if a change all 'Epand' expressions to 'Expand'. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is a mistype. Change `Epand` to `Expand` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the HTML for one of the combined cells is:

```
<td><div class="oo">11/4</div><div class="oi">13/5</div><div class="oo">11/4</div></td>
```

As far as I know, `div` layout rules don't imply a newline, so Power Query doesn't insert one. We don't run a full layout engine, so we don't know that the column width means each `div` should be on its own line.

(If anybody knows more about HTML layout semantics, let me know and I can suggest a fix to my team.)

---

You can text-replace the HTML like this to inject your own delimiter `;` in between the `div` elements

```
let
    WebPageWithReplace = (url as text, old as text, new as text) => 
        let
            Source = Web.Contents(url),
            TextReplace = Text.ToBinary(Text.Replace(Text.FromBinary(Source), old, new)),
            Page = Web.Page(TextReplace)
        in
            Page,
    Invoked = WebPageWithReplace(
        "https://www.oddschecker.com/politics/european-politics/french-election/next-president/bet-history/marine-le-pen/today#all-history",
        "</div><div",
        "</div>;<div"),
    Data = Invoked{1}[Data]
in
    Data
```

And that way `Web.Page` will still find and parse the HTML table.

[image]